# How can two people simultaneously edit one game project?

Tags: editors, asset-workflow, teamwork, workflow

I've been looking for a workflow that allows two game developers to simultaneously work in real-time on the same project, much like Roblox Studio.

I tried using Unity, but out of the box its collaborating system is not what I am looking for.

I want to be able for both of us to work simultaneously, not one to upload its project and the other to download it every 5 minutes.

We have a preference for a workflow that lets us code in Python or C# (preferably Python).

How can we accomplish this?

Comment: Use `git` or any other version control tool.

Comment: @vikarjramun - that mostly requires that both parties be working on separate assets (non-text assets can be tricky if the editors don't support it).  If that's not OP's case, a different workflow is usually better.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It could be argued that both parties working on the same asset separately indicates either a communication issue in that development team or an architectural issue in the game design (or the game engine design), at least for assets not likely to be handled well by modern DVCS systems like `git`.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at [SceneFusion for Unity](https://www.kinematicsoup.com/scene-fusion/pricing), which is free for up to 2 users and a limited number of GameObjects in the scene. That should work well with your requirement of needing C#.

If you want something built-in, you can try [Unreal's Multi-User Editing](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/MultiUserEditing/), but you'll need to find a way to use C# in that case.

Comment: Do you mean C++ for Unreal?

Comment: He means that the asker requires C#, and they'll have to find a way to get that to work in Unreal.